# Reading and Parsing Integers as Dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, file-io

My assignment's goal is to read dates from the input file, then search and map it. So I can look for a specific date or get the end dates for each month. I've spent 3 days, but I can't seem to figure out how to read or parse the file.

Here's what I tried:

1)

```
import datetime

def createDateList(filePath):
    data = open(filePath, 'r')
    dateList = []
    for space in data:
        month, day, year = map(int, space.split())
        date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        dateList.append(date1)

return dateList
```

Here's what the input looks like:

```
6 6 19707 7 20013 15 19741 7 19772 17 1983...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried to edit your question but I'm not sure what the second snippet was supposed to look like - were all those lines really commented out? If so why post them? Please edit if necessary.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, they were. The edit you made is what it would like without it.  I kept them commented just in case I might of had something helpful there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error in the first snippet is because you did `from datetime import datetime` rather than `import datetime` before doing `datetime.date`.

Also note, the parameters to `datetime.date` are ordered `(year, month, day)`.

Comment: Removing the from altogether and changing the parameters did the trick.

Comment: [datetime.date(1970, 6, 6), datetime.date(2001, 7, 7), datetime.date(1974, 3, 15), datetime.date(1977, 1, 7), datetime.date(1983, 2, 17), datetime.date(2006, 4, 6), datetime.date(2009, 1, 28), datetime.date(1973, 5, 10), datetime.date(1948, 4, 15), datetime.date(1950, 5, 25), datetime.date(3000, 12, 3), datetime.date(2200, 1, 1), datetime.date(2500, 11, 25), datetime.date(2400, 10, 31), datetime.date(1980, 2, 28), datetime.date(1980, 3, 2), datetime.date(1981, 2, 28), datetime.date(1981, 3, 3)]

Comment: My last assignment I got docked for including an "int" type cast inside a dictionary. Is there a short algorithm or command to remove all the excess "datetime.date" characters? Or do I have write another method to make those changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Those are there because those are instances of datetime.date. If you don't want that, why are you converting them to dates at all? Why not just use a tuple of ints?

Comment: I mean that as in internally it processes it and stores it as date objects, but when printed to user it comes out with just the numbers. For the extra method to write, I would use one to copy the list and convert it back to ints for printing. So, I was asking if there was a shorter way to do that. Although, you're right I could use a tuple of ints at the same time as making the date list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that parses the dates and put them in an list.

The regular expression in the split, `''\s|(?<=\d{4})(?=\d)'` says to split on whitespace OR after four consecutive digits (followed by a digit). That way, the year will be separated from the following digit(s) for the month. Those are a look behind and a look ahead constructs in the regular expression.

```
import re
from datetime import date

s = '6 6 19707 7 20013 15 19741 7 19772 17 1983'

dates = re.split(r'\s|(?<=\d{4})(?=\d)', s)

# get length less last 3
i = len(dates) - 3

j = 0
final_date = []

while j <= i:
    m, d, yr = dates[j:j+3]
    final_date.append(date(int(yr), int(m), int(d)))
    j += 3

for d in final_date:
    print(d)
```

Ouput:

```
1970-06-06
2001-07-07
1974-03-15
1977-01-07
1983-02-17
```